# Sort a list to form the largest possible number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a function that given a list of non negative integers, arranges them such that they form the largest possible number.

For example, given `[50, 2, 1, 9]`, the largest formed number is `95021`.

Here is the code that I have tried to solve the problem:

```
a = [50, 2, 1, 9]
a.sort()
ans = []
for i in range(len(a)-1,-1,-1):
    ans.append(a[i])

print ''.join(map(str,ans))
```

However, I get `50921` , as `50` is largest, but it should show `9` first.

Comment: What have you already tried to do?  How has it failed to work?

Comment: https://blog.svpino.com/2015/05/07/five-programming-problems-every-software-engineer-should-be-able-to-solve-in-less-than-1-hour?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_content=Oktopost-facebook-profile&utm_campaign=Oktopost-2015-05+General+Campaign

Comment: [The link](https://blog.svpino.com/2015/05/07/five-programming-problems-every-software-engineer-should-be-able-to-solve-in-less-than-1-hour) is (effectively) broken: *"Secure Connection Failed. An error occurred during a connection to blog.svpino.com. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR. The page ... cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified."*. If the [HTTP version](http://blog.svpino.com/2015/05/07/five-programming-problems-every-software-engineer-should-be-able-to-solve-in-less-than-1-hour) is used, then it redirects and report *"404. Page Not Found"*

Comment: Perhaps add some of the sample input data from some of the answers (and the correct result) for a better test set? And/or some other sample input data. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.) This will not invalidate any of the answers.

Comment: Some sample input from deleted answers is (may or may not be good candidates): `[2, 23, 21]` and `[1, 10]`

Answer (score 23):

In Python 2 you can do this with an appropriate comparison function passed to `sort`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Sort a list of non-negative integers so that
    if the integers were converted to string, concatenated
    and converted back to int, the resulting int is the highest
    possible for that list

    From http://stackoverflow.com/q/30140796/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.05.10

    Python 2 version
'''

data = [
    [50, 2, 1, 9],
    [10, 1],
    [2, 23, 21],
]

def mycmp(a, b):
    a, b = str(a), str(b)
    ab, ba = a + b, b + a
    if ab == ba:
        return 0
    if ab < ba:
        return -1
    return 1

for a in data:
    print 'In: ', a
    a.sort(cmp=mycmp, reverse=True)
    print 'Out:', a
    print
```

**Output**

```
In:  [50, 2, 1, 9]
Out: [9, 50, 2, 1]

In:  [10, 1]
Out: [1, 10]

In:  [2, 23, 21]
Out: [23, 2, 21]
```

---

In Python 3, `sort` no longer takes a custom comparison function. [scpio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140796/sort-a-list-to-form-the-largest-possible-number/30141799#30141799) shows how to use `functools` to convert a comparison function into a key function, but it's not that hard to do "by hand".

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Sort a list of non-negative integers so that
    if the integers were converted to string, concatenated
    and converted back to int, the resulting int is the highest
    possible for that list

    From http://stackoverflow.com/q/30140796/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.05.10

    Python 3 compatible version
'''

from __future__ import print_function

class cmpclass(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = str(n)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.n

    def _cmp(self, other):
        a, b = self.n, str(other)
        ab, ba = a + b, b + a
        if ab == ba:
            return 0
        if ab < ba:
            return -1
        return 1

    def __lt__(self, other): return self._cmp(other) == -1
    def __le__(self, other): return self._cmp(other) <= 0
    def __eq__(self, other): return self._cmp(other) == 0
    def __ne__(self, other): return self._cmp(other) != 0
    def __gt__(self, other): return self._cmp(other) == 1
    def __ge__(self, other): return self._cmp(other) >= 0


data = [
    [50, 2, 1, 9],
    [10, 1],
    [2, 23, 21],
]

for a in data:
    print('In: ', a)
    a.sort(key=cmpclass, reverse=True)
    print('Out:', a)
    print('')
```

**Output**

```
In:  [50, 2, 1, 9]
Out: [9, 50, 2, 1]

In:  [10, 1]
Out: [1, 10]

In:  [2, 23, 21]
Out: [23, 2, 21]
```

The previous Python 3 compatible version I posted doesn't actually work on Python 3 :oops:! That's because the `__cmp__` method is no longer supported in Python 3. So I've changed my old `__cmp__` method to `_cmp` and used it to implement all 6 of the [rich comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).

**Important note**

An alternative strategy that's *guaranteed* to work is brute force: generate all permutations of the input list & find the permutation that yields the maximum result. But hopefully there's a more efficient algorithm, since generating all permutations of a large list is rather slow.

---

As [Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918959/antti-haapala-%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%96) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140796/sort-a-list-to-form-the-largest-possible-number/30141885#comment48412019_30141885) in the comments, my old comparison functions were unstable when comparing different numbers that consist of the same sequences of repeating digits, e.g., 123123 and 123123123. Such sequences should compare equal, my old functions didn't do that. The latest modification addresses that problem.

---

**Update**

It turns out that `mycmp() / _cmp()` actually *is* transitive. It's also stable, now that it handles the `ab == ba` case properly, so it's safe to use with [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) (or any other sorting algorithm). And it can be shown that it gives the same result as Antti Haapala's `fractionalize()` key function.

In what follows I'll use uppercase letters to represent integers in the list and I'll use the lowercase version of a letter to represent the number of digits in that integer. E.g., `a` is the number of digits in `A`. I'll use `_` as an infix operator to represent digit concatenation. Eg, `A_B` is `int(str(A)+str(B)`; note that `A_B` has `a+b` digits. Arithmetically,
`A_B = A * 10**b + B`.

For the sake of brevity, I'll use `f()` to represent Antti Haapala's `fractionalize()` key function. Note that `f(A) = A / (10**a - 1)`.

Now for some algebra. I'll put it in a code block to keep the formatting simple.

```
Let A_B = B_A
A * 10**b + B = B * 10**a + A
A * 10**b - A = B * 10**a - B
A * (10**b - 1) = B * (10**a - 1)
A / (10**a - 1) = B / (10**b - 1)
f(A) = f(B)

So A_B = B_A if & only if f(A) = f(B)

Similarly,
A_B > B_A if & only if f(A) > f(B)
This proves that using mycmp() / _cmp() as the sort comparison function
is equivalent to using fractionalize() as the sort key function.

Note that
f(A_B) = (A * 10**b + B) / (10**(a+b)-1)
and
f(B_A) = (B * 10**a + A) / (10**(a+b)-1)

So f(A_B) = f(B_A) iff A_B = B_A, and f(A_B) > f(B_A) iff A_B > B_A

Let's see what happens with 3 integers.

f(A), f(B), f(C) are just real numbers, so comparing them is
transitive.
And so if f(A) > f(B) and f(B) > f(C) then f(A) > f(C).
This proves that mycmp() / _cmp() is also transitive.

Clearly, if f(A) > f(B) > f(C) then
A_B > B_A, B_C > C_B, A_C > C_A

Let B_C > C_B
For any A,
A * 10**(b+c) + B_C > A * 10**(b+c) + C_B
So A_B_C > A_C_B
i.e. adding the same integer to the beginning of B_C and C_B preserves
the inequality.

Let A_B > B_A
For any C,
(A_B) * 10**c + C > (B_A) * 10**c + C
So A_B_C > B_A_C,
i.e. adding the same integer to the end of A_B and B_A preserves the
inequality.

Using these results, we can show that
if f(A) > f(B) > f(C) then
A_B_C > A_C_B > C_A_B > C_B_A and
A_B_C > B_A_C > B_C_A > C_B_A.

This covers all 6 permutations of [A, B, C] and shows that A_B_C is the
largest possible integer for that list.
```

A mathematical induction-style argument shows that sorting a list of any
finite length using pairwise comparisons with `mycmp()` / `_cmp()` as the
comparison function or with `fractionalize()` as the key function suffices
to find the permutation that yields the largest possible integer
produced by digit concatenation. The details of this argument will be
left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: The Py3 version doesn't work for me, I get `TypeError: unorderable types: cmpclass() < cmpclass()`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I've fixed that problem. However, as I mention in the **Important note** there's a fundamental flaw in my algorithm. Fortunately Antti Hapala has posted a much better solution.

Comment: How do you know it's not transitive?

Comment: @StefanPochmann it is transitive and equivalent to my algorithm, I just made PM 2Ring a bit confused when I asked that how does he know that it is transitive...

Comment: @StefanPochmann there is a slight bug, numbers that are prefixes of each other, say `22` and `222` are unstable...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala But that doesn't cause a problem, does it?

Comment: It does, timsort requires that the comparison function is stable and transitive, otherwise it could output erroneous output.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala When comparing 22 and 222, `cmp` says 0 both ways, and `<` says False both ways. The two numbers are just regarded as equal. Do you have a full example that goes wrong?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Your linked code may work ok with the current implementation of TimSort, but to be robust a class that defines any of the rich comparison methods really should implement all 6 of them, since there's no telling what comparisons a client may invoke.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Actually, my comparison function **is** transitive. :oops:  My confusion arose from inappropriate mixing of raw integer comparison with the custom comparison function.

Answer (score 13):

One-liner using insights from [Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140796/sort-a-list-to-form-the-largest-possible-number/30152085#30152085), [PM 2Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140796/sort-a-list-to-form-the-largest-possible-number/30141885#30141885) and [Stefan Pochmann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140796/sort-a-list-to-form-the-largest-possible-number/30140850#comment48455555_30152085):

```
from fractions import Fraction
sorted(a, key=lambda n: Fraction(n, 1-10**len(str(n))))
```

Given `a = [50, 5, 51, 59, 2, 1, 9, 98]`:

```
[9, 98, 59, 5, 51, 50, 2, 1]
```

Comment: `10 ** len(str(n)) - 1` actually seemed to be quite fast

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yeah, that does seem quite a bit faster. Updated, thanks!

Comment: Intriguing answer, especially the mysterious "insights" that are mentioned.

Comment: Shortened: `sorted(a, key=lambda n: Fraction(n, 1-10**len(str(n))))`

Comment: @KellyBundy of course, why not just reverse the math instead of doing it separately? How elegant, can't believe I didn't think of that!

Comment: @Stef the insights are just gleaned from reading their answers and comments to this same question, no secrets! :)

Answer (score 9):

Here is an ugly solution that does work without passing a `cmp` comparison  function to the `sorted`. Basically, the key function takes each number and calculates a rational number that has that number as the [repeating decimals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal); that is

```
0   => 0
100 => 100/999 == 0.100100100...
10  => 10/99   == 0.1010101010...
1   => 1/9     == 0.1111111111...
11  => 11/99   == 0.1111111111...
12  => 12/99   == 0.1212121212...
9   => 9/9     == 1
99  => 99/99   == 1
999 => 999/999 == 1
```

The 0 is sorted the smallest with sort key 0, and 1 followed by most zeroes would have key closest to `0.1`, and thus sorted second smallest. Numbers that consist of digit 9 all have sort key equal to `1`; it does not really matter if you sort `9` before or after `99`.

Sorting using these values as the key will necessarily give the correct output, unless you use numbers that are too big for float precision. (probably much sooner than `2 ** 53`)

Thus we get the following program:

```
# for Python 2, not needed in Python 3
from __future__ import division

a = [50, 5, 51, 59, 2, 1, 9, 98]

def fractionalize(i):
    divisor = 9
    while divisor < i:
        divisor = 10 * divisor + 9 

    return i / divisor

print(sorted(a, key=fractionalize, reverse=True))
```

Which produces

```
[9, 98, 59, 5, 51, 50, 2, 1]
```

---

As we're essentially calculating `i / (10 ** ceil(log10(i + 1)) - 1)` here, one can also write the following oneliner:

```
from math import ceil, log10

print(sorted(a, key=lambda i: i and i/(10**ceil(log10(i+1))-1), reverse=True))
```

The `i and` part guards for division by zero error, in case `0` is among the numbers.

Comment: Might as well use `key=lambda n:str(n)*100`, right?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Ok but how about using `Fraction`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: 1) `str(n)*100` is a bit wasteful of RAM, but I guess it won't slow the comparisons down much. 2) A `Fraction` is good because it allows the list to contain `int`s that are too big for float precision. OTOH, `Fraction` comparison is slower than `float` comparison, since it needs to do two multiplications on top of the (possibly short-circuited) subtraction.

Comment: It's a pity that integers don't have a decimal equivalent of [.bit_length()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length). But I guess you could calculate the number of digits in `i` by dividing the bit length by log10(2).

Comment: dividing by log2(10) you mean ;-)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Yes, I do.  (Numerical dyslexia strikes again :) ). Or _multiplying_ by log10(2).

Comment: Actually, on second thoughts, that wouldn't work very well, since `i.bit_length()` isn't a very precise measure of `log2(i)`.

Comment: You can as well perform the comparison on the string representation of the two numbers, and simulate the repetition by cycling the character index in the shortest string. E.g. to compare 12345/99999 to 12/99, it suffices to compare 12345 to 12|12|1.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Wouldn't that incorrectly say that 12121 and 12 are equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

My input is cast as a list of strings.  I generate the list of permutations, creating a list of lists, and then sort the sublists from least to greatest.  Finally, I take the last element of the sorted list.

```
import itertools

digits = ['50', '2', '1', '9']
perms = itertools.permutations(digits)
sorted_numlist = sorted(perms)
print sorted_numlist[-1]
```

If you'd rather have the number itself rather than the list of elements...

```
import itertools

digits = ['11', '68', '4', '12']
perms = itertools.permutations(digits)
numlist = []
for sublist in perms:
    permutated_num = "".join(sublist)
    numlist.append(int(permutated_num))

sorted_numlist = sorted(numlist)
print sorted_numlist[-1]
```

That second one actually also serves to show the first is properly sorting on lists.

Answer (score -1):

The most straightforward way is to use [*itertools.permutations()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) to model how you would solve this by hand:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations, imap
>>> a = [50, 2, 1, 9]
>>> int(max(imap(''.join, permutations(map(str, a)))))
95021
```

Comment: Gives wrong result for `a = [50, 5, 51, 59, 2, 1, 9, 98]`

Comment: Kostas, it produces a correct result, but that requires a `long` if run on a 32-bit Python 2. `permutations` was introduced in 2.6, but you'd have to go all the way back to 2.2 to get an `int` that doesn't produce `long` (and therefore is incorrect). In Python 3, you'd use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) rather than [`imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap), and `int` already handles arbitrary precision.

Answer (score -1):

This version works for me:

```
def arrange(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(lst)):
            if int(str(lst[j]+lst[i])) > int(str(lst[i]+lst[j])):
                temp = lst[i]
                lst[i] = lst[j]
                lst[j] = temp
    for i in lst:
        print(i, end="")

lst = [i for i in input().split()]
arrange(lst)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Using [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)?

Answer (score -1):

```
def make_it_large_num(l):
    lst = [str(x) for x in l]
    print(sorted(lst, reverse=True))
    res = ''.join(sorted(lst, reverse=True))
    print(res)


lst = [50,2,1,9]
make_it_large_num(lst)
```

This works for me. Simple and no need use any libraries (Python 3).

Comment: It only seems to work because of your badly chosen test data. You should always test your code on data for which you have the expected output. For `lst = [50, 5, 51, 59, 2, 1, 9, 98]`, you get `['98', '9', '59', '51', '50', '5', '2', '1']  989595150521` which is clearly wrong.

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille: Note that the input data is from the example in the question.

Comment: @PeterMortensen That's right, I have taken the data used in two of the most upvoted answers, which is good for testing, and didn't notice that it didn't come from the question.

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille: Thanks for analysing this answer. Most late answers on Stack Overflow are uncontested, and many are completely bogus and/or plagiarised.

Answer (score -2):

```
import functools

def cmpr(x, y):
    xy = str(x) + str(y)
    yx = str(y) + str(x)
    return -1 if (xy > yx) else 1

a = [50, 2, 1, 9]
a.sort(key=functools.cmp_to_key(cmpr))
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to this code.

Comment: I don't think this will work, even on the given example; your comparison function doesn't return the right values for a cmp.

Comment: did this in a hurry and forgot that a sort comparator returns -1 or 1 instead of 0 and 1. But my answer was already roughly replicated by @PM 2Ring, so take either ;)

Comment: @scpio: An old-style comparison function needs to return _three_ different values, not just two. It needs to return `(negative, zero, positive)` for `(<, ==, >)`, respectively.

Comment: scpio has left the building: *"Last seen more than 7 years ago"*

Answer (score -2):

---

List item

```
def create_largest_number(number_list):
    res=''
    for i in number_list:
        res= res+ str(i)
        new=''.join(sorted(res))
    return new[::-1]       

number_list=[23,45,67]
largest_number=create_largest_number(number_list)
print(largest_number)
```