# python string compare issue in a list

Tags: python

I want to reorder number members in a list (the list contains number only), and if string form of num1 + string form of num2 >= string form of num2 + string form of num1, then num1 should be ahead of num2 (I cannot compare numbers directly since a number may be very large, or the concatenated string format of a number could be very large and overflow). Here is an example,

```
num1 = 3
num2 = 30
```

since num1+num2 > num2+num1 #'330' > '303'

so, 3 should be ahead of 30

Another example, input is [3, 30, 34, 5, 9], and expected output is [9, 5, 34, 3, 30], and wondering how to write Python code elegantly? Could we write a customized cmp method for a Python list?

It seems this method not working? After sorted step, l is still the same as original value?

```
def cmp_values(v1, v2):
    _v1 = int('{0}{1}'.format(v1, v2))
    _v2 = int('{0}{1}'.format(v2, v1))
    return cmp(_v2, _v1)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    l = [3, 30, 34, 5, 9]
    sorted(l, cmp=cmp_values)
    print l
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.x, and an elegant solution for Python 2 series are appreciated. :)

Comment: FWIW, it _is_ possible to do this in Python 3, even though Python 3 doesn't support the `cmp` function argument of `list.sort()`. The trick is to implement a class with rich comparison arguments. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30141885/4014959) an answer I wrote 6 months ago that has both Python 2 and Python 3 implementations of this particular comparison.

Comment: Also note [Antti Haapala's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30152085/4014959) to that question , which performs this sort using a true key function, which makes it more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom cmp method to sort the list:

```
def cmp_values(v1, v2):
    _v1 = int('{0}{1}'.format(v1, v2))
    _v2 = int('{0}{1}'.format(v2, v1))
    return cmp(_v2, _v1)
```

and then use it to sort the list

```
In [5]: l = [3, 30, 34, 5, 9]
In [6]: sorted(l, cmp=cmp_values)
Out[6]: [9, 5, 34, 3, 30]
```

You do need to take care of the overflow issue though. In case the combination of v1, and v2 exceeds the int range.

**Based on further comments from @LinMa**

Using `sorted` wouldn't change the original list, so you need to assign the returned list to a new variable:

```
new_list = sorted(l, cmp=cmp_values)
```

Comment: Considering the OP's comment `Could we write a customized cmp method for a Python list?` I assumed he knows about how does this work. But I do agree that adding this would help other users as well. Thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: Can the down voter comment why the answer is not correct ?

Comment: @AKS, tried your method, and posted my code below, and it returns the same array of original l, it seems not ordered?

 `def cmp_values(v1, v2):
    _v1 = int('{0}{1}'.format(v1, v2))
    _v2 = int('{0}{1}'.format(v2, v1))
    return cmp(_v2, _v1)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    l = [3, 30, 34, 5, 9]
    sorted(l, cmp=cmp_values)
    print l`

Comment: @AKS, some format issue in comments and add my code in my original post, and your advice is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: @AKS, I am using Python 2.7.x, could it be a reason not working as you did in your environment? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa: Glad to be of help.

Comment: @LinMa: The `sorted()` function is a convenience function that creates a copy of the original list and then sorts that list in-place using the `list.sort() method`, so it's wasteful to use  `sorted()` when you actually do want an in-place sort.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague...

Next time, make sure to format your code properly using proper indentations (found by clicking `Code` below the 'Undo' arrow.

When it comes to sorting out a list, just use `.sort()` function, like so:

```
new_list = [3,6,1,2,4,5]

new_list.sort()

print(new_list)
```

This should return:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This is the simplest explanation of how to sort it. Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as AKS. Longer code but maybe easy to follow steps.

```
list = [3, 30, 34, 5, 9, 8]

job_done = False
while(job_done == False):
    job_done = True
    for i in range(len(list) - 1):
        as_is = int('{0}{1}'.format(list[i], list[i + 1]))
        swaped = int('{0}{1}'.format(list[i + 1], list[i]))
        if as_is < swaped:
            tmp = list[i]
            list[i] = list[i + 1]
            list[i + 1] = tmp
            job_done = False
print list
```