# Sort a list with longest items first

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lambda

I am using a lambda to modify the behaviour of sort.

```
sorted(list, key=lambda item:(item.lower(),len(item)))
```

Sorting a list containing the elements `A1,A2,A3,A,B1,B2,B3,B`, the result is `A,A1,A2,A3,B,B1,B2,B3`.

My expected sorted list would be `A1,A2,A3,A,B1,B2,B3,B`.

I've already tried to include the `len(item)` for sorting, which didn't work. How to modify the lambda so that the sort result is instead?

Comment: Do you really need to `lower` the case? It's a distraction in the question.

Comment: lower is done to do a case insensitive sort. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: But your data is all uppercase.

Comment: Are these actually strings? Like `'A1','A2','A3',` etc. or variables? If variables what do they contain?

Comment: there's a conflict between the alphanum sort and the length sort. Not sure that can be done without some hardcoding.

Comment: Will it always be either a letter and a number, or a single letter?

Comment: We need a better description of your sort criteria, or at least a few more examples of sample input & expected output.

Comment: The items in the list are always strings. Characters may contained in these strings are `[A-Za-z0-9\.]`. The above example shows sample data which I am using to examine the issue.

Comment: I don't know why someone voted to close.  This is a really interesting question whose correct answer would elude most Python programmers.  The only odd part of the question is why someone would want this particular sort order.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger I am using a python script to verify if a sort mechanism was executed on a file. As the sort mechanism cannot be changed, I have to do the same sort in my script (`if sorted != unsorted`).

Comment: @k_wave In that case, your problem is both interesting *and* practical :-)

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way to do it:

```
>>> import functools
>>> def cmp(s, t):
    'Alter lexicographic sort order to make longer keys go *before* any of their prefixes'
    ls, lt = len(s), len(t)
    if ls < lt:   s += t[ls:] + 'x'
    elif lt < ls: t += s[lt:] + 'x'
    if s < t: return -1
    if s > t: return 1
    return 0

>>> sorted(l, key=functools.cmp_to_key(cmp))
['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B']
```

Traditionally, lexicographic sort order longer strings *after* their otherwise identical prefixes (i.e.  'abc' goes before 'abcd').

To meet your sort expectation, we first "fix-up" the shorter string by adding the remaining part of the longer string plus another character to make it the longer of the two:

```
compare abc to defg     -->  compare abcgx to defg
compare a   to a2       -->  compare a2x to a2
```

The *functools.cmp_to_key()* tool then converts the comparison function to a key function.

This may seem like a lot of work, but the sort expectations are very much at odds with the built-in lexicographic sorting rules.

FWIW, here's another way of writing it, that might or might not be considered clearer:

```
def cmp(s, t):
    'Alter lexicographic sort order to make longer keys go *before* any of their prefixes'
    for p, q in zip(s, t):
        if p < q: return -1
        if q < p: return 1
    if len(s) > len(t): return -1
    elif len(t) > len(s): return 1
    return 0
```

The logic is:

- Compare character by character until a different pair is found
- That differing pair determines the sort order in the traditional way
- If there is no differing pair, then longest input goes first.
- If there is no differing pair and the lengths are equal, the strings are equal.

Comment: Oops, even the @RaymondHettinger, missed out code indentation :D

Comment: @IronFist I wrote the code in the way that I find to be clearest.  Sometimes, the guarded statement style favored by mathematicians is clearer and easier to reason about.   Even in the standard library, we sometimes put the test and action statement on the same line (for example, see Lib/bisect.py).

Comment: With weird sorting criteria like this it's a shame we no longer have a `cmp` arg for `sort` / `sorted`. But I guess that the kind of Schwartzian transform that `functools.cmp_to_key` performs doesn't add too much overhead on top of what using `cmp` directly does.

Comment: @PM2Ring *functools.cmp_to_key* has a somewhat simple and low overhead pure python implementation and an even lower overhead (almost cost-free) C implementation.  The *functools.cmp_to_key* tool was put in just to handle this sort of extraordinary case of a weird cmp-function. In almost every other case, cmp-functions are the wrong thing to do (three-way compares are generally more complex than boolean key-functions, and cmp-functions are O(n log n) as compared to key-functions which are O(n).  SQL's ORDER BY clauses use key-functions and they solve a tremendous variety of real-world problems.

Comment: You may find the various key & cmp strategies in this old question entertaining: [Sort a list to form the largest possible number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140796/sort-a-list-to-form-the-largest-possible-number)

Answer (score 1):

My first answer was: just negate the `len` criterion to reverse only on that criterion.

```
sorted(list, key=lambda item:(item.lower(),-len(item)))   # doesn't work!
```

But that doesn't work, because there's a conflict between alpha sort and length. Alpha sort puts small strings first. So length criterion doesn't work.

You need to merge both criteria. There's no clear priority between each other.

I found a way: first compute the max length of your strings, then return the `chr(127)` filled (the biggest char provided you're using only ASCII) version of the string as key so smallest strings are filled with big chars in the end: they always come last.

```
l = ["A","B","A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3"]

maxlen = max(len(x) for x in l)
print(sorted(l, key=lambda item:item.lower()+chr(127)*(maxlen-len(item))))
```

result:

```
['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B']
```

BTW don't call your list `list` for obvious reasons.

Comment: this doesn't work either. I'am getting the same result `A,A1,A2,A3,B,B1,B2,B3`

Comment: What I like about this answer is that it focuses on the crux of the problem, "a conflict between alpha sort and length".  What I don't like is that the answer is not general. It presumes the largest character is ``ord(126)`` which isn't necessarily the case for general Python 3 unicode inputs, and it presumes pre-knowledge of the maximum length of the inputs.  To get around these limitations and make a general solution, it is necessary to make a custom cmp-function and wrap it in cmp_to_key() to make it a key-function acceptable to Python 3's *sorted()* which only accepts key-functions.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: OP did specify that the strings only include `[A-Za-z0-9\.]`

Comment: @EricDuminil A better solution wouldn't rely on that particular.  For SO, we would like the solutions to be as re-useable and robust as possible.

Comment: I tried to use the fact that some objects (e.g. tuples) will always be sorted after strings. I didn't achieve anything, though.

Comment: Shoot, it doesn't work anymore in Python 3 : `TypeError` :-/

Comment: I think (if you are going to hard code the largest character) you can simply do `sorted(l, key=lambda x: x+chr(127))`? So you don't need to consider the max string length at all

Answer (score 0):

One could construct the key by taking:

1. the first letter of every item
2. the length
3. the item itself

For example:

```
>>> L = ['A1', 'B2', 'A', 'A2', 'B1', 'A3', 'B3', 'B']
>>> print(sorted(L, key = lambda item: (item[0], -len(item), item)))
['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B']
```

Comment: Possibly, although that's not case insensitive. To handle that, I suggest using a proper `def` function rather than a `lambda` to avoid calling `.lower` twice. However, we still don't have a clear specification of the sort criteria.  Who knows, perhaps numeric portions may need to be compared numerically...

Comment: There should be a recursive call. Otherwise, it would only work for strings of 1 or 2 chars.

Comment: @EricDuminil indeed, from the original question it wasn't very clear how the input looks like in general...

Answer (score 0):

I love Tries, so just for fun, I wrote a Trie-based solution :

```
class Trie():

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def add(self, word):
        ref = self.data
        for char in word:
            ref[char] = char in ref and ref[char] or {}
            ref = ref[char]
        ref[''] = 1


def sorted_print(dct, prefix=''):
    sorted_keys = sorted(filter(bool, dct.keys()), key=str.lower)
    for key in sorted_keys:
        v = dct[key]
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            sorted_print(v, prefix + key)
    if '' in dct:
        print(prefix)

my_list = ["B1", "B3", "B2", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A", "B"]
t = Trie()
for w in my_list:
    t.add(w)


sorted_print(t.data)
# A1
# A2
# A3
# A
# B1
# B2
# B3
# B
```

This should work for any string of any length.

Note that the result is just printed to screen, not written back in a new list. You didn't write much code, so I'll leave it as an exercise ;)