# How to sort by alphabetical order followed by length of string?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm currently new to python and got stuck at this question, can't seem to find the proper answer.

I have a list contain :

```
BLUE
BLUE-ELMWOOD-CAMO
BLUE-MIST
BLUE-MIST-SPRING-LEAF
BLUE-MULTI
BOTTLE-GREEN
CABANA-BLUE
CAPRI-NAVY
```

And I want to sort like this :

```
BLUE-ELMWOOD-CAMO
BLUE-MIST-SPRING-LEAF
BLUE-MIST
BLUE-MULTI
BLUE
BOTTLE-GREEN
CABANA-BLUE
CAPRI-NAVY
```

Like this:

[image]

I've tried `list.sort()` but it gives the first one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899405/sort-a-list-with-longest-items-first has some solutions to try.

Comment: So its alphabetical for first word then total length ? Why BLUE-MULTI is after BLUE-MIST ?

Comment: @RyanSchaefer yep `values.sort(key = lambda x: (x.split("-")[0], -len(x)))` is the one

Comment: @azro I believe it’s actually alphabetical of the longest prefix then by length of the remaining. It’s pretty confusing to be honest and I’m not entirely sure it is a consistent rule. So all have “BLUE” in the first “group”. Regular “BLUE” is then “disqualified” as it isn’t longer than any other word with the same prefix. Then E comes first alphabetically. Then the next two match until most wherein the length breaks the tie. Then “MULTI” comes after that. The author would have to be more specific for the tie breakers here I think.