# largest fromed number in a list python

Tags: python, sorting

question:
Given a list of non negative integers, arrange them such that they form the largest number.

So given [1, 20, 23, 4, 8], the largest formed number is 8423201.

I just couldn't understand the following solution:

What does `num.sort(cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(y + x, x + y))` do?

And why does it have two parameters x and y? If input a list, what does x and y represent in the list?

```
class Solution:
    # @param num, a list of integers
    # @return a string
    def largestNumber(self, num):
        num = [str(x) for x in num]
        num.sort(cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(y + x, x + y))
        largest = ''.join(num)
        return largest.lstrip('0') or '0'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num = [3, 30, 34, 5, 9]
    print Solution().largestNumber(num)
```

Can somebody explain the code solution? Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, that code will only work on Python 2. The use of the `cmp` function argument to `sort` is deprecated, and no longer exists in Python 3. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140796/sort-a-list-to-form-the-largest-possible-number for various solutions to this problem. You can read what `cmp` does in `sort` in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), see Note 8. Also see the docs for the built-in [`cmp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp).

Comment: This is using an old style compare function to order the list, it uses string concatenation and comparison to order, e.g. `'3'+'30' (330) > '30'+'3' (303)`, this will force `'8'` to the front of the list because `"8XX" > "XX8"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation of the code.

```
class Solution:
    # @param num, a list of integers
    # @return a string
    def largestNumber(self, num):
        # converts list of numbers to list of strings
        num = [str(x) for x in num]
        # sorts list based on comparator function provided (an "anonymous" lambda function)
        # the comparator is used to compare pairs of elements for sorting (x comes first returns -1, "equal" returns 0, x comes after returns 1)
        # the lambda function takes two arguments x and y because comparator takes two arguments
        # since these are strings, they are compared by seeing which concatenation (+ operator with strings) 
        # comes "first" alphabetically but note the x and y are "swapped" from what you might expect (to reverse the sort)
        num.sort(cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(y + x, x + y))
        # join the sorted list together with empty string separators
        largest = ''.join(num)
        # remove any leading 0s
        return largest.lstrip('0') or '0'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num = [3, 30, 34, 5, 9]
    print Solution().largestNumber(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.x sort functions allowed a `cmp` function for comparing two items. `cmp(a, b)` returns -1 if a < b, 0 if a == b, or 1 if a > b.

This code uses `cmp` "creatively" to get the needed sort order to solve the problem; it will sort "8" before "80" because "880" > "808".

The problem is that you want a reverse alphabetical sort, BUT you want short strings before long ones (if their prefixes are identical).

A more general solution would be to reverse-sort alphabetically, but right-pad all the strings to the same length - at least as long as the longest string you are sorting - with a character which sorts as "greater than 9".

How do we choose such a character? Well,

```
ord("9")                                         # -> 57
print("".join(chr(ch) for ch in range(57, 75))   # "9:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJ"
```

So `"A"` looks like a good choice, and it's easy to remember because it's 10 in hexadecimal.

Then

```
def largest_number(nums):
    # convert to strings
    nums = [str(i) for i in nums]

    # find the length of the longest string
    longest = max(len(s) for s in nums)

    # create a function to pad strings to that length
    def padded(s, pad_char="A", length=longest):
        return s + pad_char * (length - len(s))

    # sort the strings greatest-to-least according to their padded values
    nums.sort(key=padded, reverse=True)
    # nums is now ["9", "5", "3", "34", "30"]

    # get the resulting output-string
    num = "".join(nums)

    # remove any leading 0s
    #  (this should only ever occur if all input nums were 0)
    num = num.lstrip("0")

    if num:
        return num
    else:
        # the string was all 0s - return a single 0
        return "0"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nums = [3, 30, 34, 5, 9]
    print(largest_number(nums))   # -> "9533430"
```

Answer (score -5):

`list.sort(function)` sort your list with the `function` you have indicated.