# How to use sorted using key=lambda instead of cmp_to_key?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, custom-compare

Given an array A of non-negative integers, arrange them such that they form the largest number.
example :

```
 A = [3, 30, 34, 5, 9]
 output : "9534330"
```

I am able to do this using custom compare function, is it possible to achieve the same using lambda?

Code:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

A = list(map(str,A))

def compare(num1,num2):
    if num1 + num2 > num2 + num1:
        return -1           
    else:
        return 1

A = sorted(A,key=cmp_to_key(compare))
return "".join(A)
```

Comment: This is the one case I know of where it's cleanest to just stick to a comparator function and `functools.cmp_to_key` instead of trying to write a key function by hand.

Comment: From [cmp_to_key 's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key): *"A comparison function is any callable that accepts two arguments, compares them, and returns a negative number for less-than, zero for equality, or a positive number for greater-than."* So presumably your `compare` function should be rewritten

Comment: (Though you really ought to handle the `num1 + num2 == num2 + num1` case in your comparator.)

Comment: It's good to have a well-written question with a good answer here, especially if we expect future duplicates :)

Comment: In the linked "duplicate" I don't see a single answer that addresses the question of whether it would be possible without cmp_to_key...

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30189892/12671057) of the duplicate original fits.

Comment: Interesting, although it contains absolutely no explanation for the formula used in the key

Comment: @Stef Yes, could be better, but it does reference names of people whose answers/comments contain explanations.

Comment: @Stef Why did you say their compare function should be rewritten?

Comment: @Stef I guess because of the `==` case? That's intriguing. My intuition says that if they returned `-1` in that case, it would be safe because that's a stable sort. But now they *swap* "equals", and I'm rather uncertain about that. Might confuse Timsort by giving it conflicting information.

Comment: @KellyBundy The documentation of `cmp_to_key` explicitly states that the compare function should return `0` for two equivalent elements. Currently it returns `1`. So it might or might not work, but that would be implementation dependent. Better to return 0 when we're supposed to return 0.

Comment: @Stef It would certainly be better. I'm not quite convinced it's necessary. What does "less-than" mean? If we do ascending case-insensitive stable sort and we have the list `['Foo', 'fOo']` and you ask me which of the two strings is smaller, it might be ok to consider `'Foo'` not equal but *smaller*. Not because of its *value*, which equals the other,  but because of its *position*. Then again, that requires taking the algorithm into consideration for the comparison. Hmm. When asked to compare two, I won't know which one has the smaller position. Ok ok, I fully agree with you now :-)